# 500 No response from subprocess (php): subprocess exited with status 127

Tags: centos, php, ssh

Got an issue at the moment, where any of the cpanel webmails are accessed, we are getting

500
 No response from subprocess (php): subprocess exited with status 127

I've tried the following;

```
yum install libltdl.so.3 (nothing todo)
yum reinstall "libtool-ltdl" (same)
cp /usr/lib/libltdl.so.3 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/53/bin/
/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix


localte libltdl.so.3
/usr/lib/libltdl.so.3 
/usr/lib/libltdl.so.3.1.4 
/usr/local/cpanel/lib/libltdl.so.3 
/usr/local/cpanel/lib64/libltdl.so.3 

php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 26 2013 11:46:30)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd.
```

Cpanel error log;

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/53/bin/php-cgi: error while loading shared libraries: libltdl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Internal Server Error: "GET /cpsess2428956043/3rdparty/roundcube/index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 No response from subprocess (php): subprocess exited with status 127
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to let everyone know. Here is the solution to the above.

The issue was that /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/53/bin/php-cgi was looking for /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libltdl.so.3 but this didn't exist. Thus, what I did to correct the issue was symlink the libltdl.so.3 binary from /usr/local/cpanel/lib64/libltdl.so.3 to /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libltdl.so.3 and am no longer seeing any further issues.

This is command that was executed.

```
[14:44:58 lightning root@4290311 ~]cPs# ln -s /usr/local/cpanel/lib64/libltdl.so.3 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libltdl.so.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
libltdl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Your PHP interpreter at `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/53/bin/php-cgi` (which probably isn't the one you are running when you run `php`) can't run because it can't be linked to its missing shared library.  This produces exit status 127.  The missing library is libltdl, which is GNU libtool, but it looks like you actually do have it installed.

Check the value of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the environment under which the php interpreter is running.  It has to include a directory which contains libltdl.so.3.  Probably you want to include either `/usr/local/cpanel/lib/` or `/usr/local/cpanel/lib64/` in that, or both (but you could also just include `/usr/lib/`).

Comment: The environment in which the php interpreter is running is handled by cpanel. So the question becomes in which file do I add in the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I'd ask their support.  Most of us here find cPanel to be a horrible crutch and don't bother with its internals, and this kind of looks like a failed update of some kind.